# I'm unable to get the preview of Navigation drawer even after adding tools:showIn="navigation_view" in the .xml file

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am new to android development and I was designing a navigation drawer and I am using java and android studio 3.6.2 but after writing the following code I am not getting the navigation drawer.
I want to know if I'm missing something in the .xml file or I have not written any important dependencies?
Please Help!

I have written the following  code. 
build.gradle(:app) and also
i have written the dependencies implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.navigationdrawer"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}


In the .xml file i have included the
``
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view"
```

drawer_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_message"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_message"
            android:title="Message" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_chat"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat"
            android:title="Chat" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:title="Profile" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_send"
                android:title="Share" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[I'm getting this type of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFavz.png)

Comment: What is your main XML?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution!! just make another xmlfile layoutfile.xml(Any name) in the layout under res and include the following code. It worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation1_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```